# How to extract and append objects from an array of objects in JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

The question is pretty straight forward. I feel dumb asking this because I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, but anyways here is the question.

I'm given a response data and the JSON is sort of like this:

```
$scope.testData = [
        {
            food: 'wet',
            animal: [{name: 'cat', value: '1'},
                    {name: 'dog', value: '2'}]
        },
        {
            food: 'dry',
            animal: [{name: 'bird', value: '3'},
                    {name: 'fish', value: '4'}]
        }
    ];
```

The question at hand is how can I pull the nested objects under `animal` so I can set a string up and and push it with the current food object for example:

I would take out the animal: names
so under object with `food: 'wet'` I would take out animal:

```
[{name: 'cat', value: '1'},
 {name: 'dog', value: '2'}]
```

Then I would take the object names 'cat' and 'dog' put into a string like cat, dog and then push the new values into a new array of objects that look like this

```
$scope.newData = [
        {
            food: 'wet',
            animalType: 'cat, dog'
        },
        {
            food: 'dry',
            animalType: 'bird, fish'
        }
    ];
```

This is all done so I can have a cleaner UI grid

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
  $scope.newData = $scope.testData.map(function(obj){
    return {
      food: obj.food,
      animal: obj.animal.map(function(a){
        return a.name;
      }).join(', ') // special shout out to @vanev_ for making it a comma separated list
    }
  });

  console.log($scope.newData);
```

Comment: I noticed the typo mistake, but I tried your method and for some odd reason I'm getting back data.map is not a function when it's almost exactly like the sample I provided. I'm actually stumped now. I understand I forgot the use of map but now even when trying to apply it, it's almost as if the map fails to recognize my arrays. 

the first testData is an array we go inside with map and pull the objects the second map goes into another array... the probelm is that is fails at first call of .map

Comment: I made a quick plunk to test it: https://plnkr.co/edit/cYtA6cI9l78y7VET86ch?p=preview (Check the console for the final output).

Comment: am I missing a call? it keeps giving me data.map is not a function

Comment: I figured it out, I had accidentally set the data call wrong haha it works flawlessly

Answer (score 4):

It's really great that you've already broken the problem down into steps, now we just need to understand the tools we can use to turn those steps into code!

First, we are going to want to run the same operation over every time in this collection and return a brand new collection. This is called `map`.

We can map over our `data` by writing:

```
data.map((item) => { .. });
```

This will return a brand new collection where each item is the result of passing the item in `data` to the function given to `map`.

Next, we want to take our `animal` collection and convert it from a collection to a new collection using `map`, then `join` that new collection into a single value, a string.

We can do this to our `animal` by writing:

```
animal.map((item) => { .. }).join(', ');
```

This will return a single string, joined with whatever you give to `join`.

Let's take a look at the final code, below.

```
const data = [
  {
    food: 'wet',
    animal: [
      {
        name: 'cat',
        value: '1'
      },
      {
        name: 'dog',
        value: '2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    food: 'dry',
    animal: [
      {
        name: 'bird',
        value: '3'
      },
      {
        name: 'fish',
        value: '4'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const finalData = data.map((item) => {
  return {
    food: item.food,
    animalType: item.animal.map((item) => {
      return item.name;
    }).join(', ')
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm giving you credit well, the first guy I put as the answer but you also applied the ', ' in it which helped out A LOT! Everyone here though helped me out a lot.

Comment: Yes, great shout about `.join(', ')` plus1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` method on the array to do things like this. It would look something like this.

```
var data = [
  {
    food: 'wet',
    animal: [{name: 'cat', value: '1'},
                    {name: 'dog', value: '2'}]
  },
  {
    food: 'dry',
    animal: [{name: 'bird', value: '3'},
                    {name: 'fish', value: '4'}]
  }
];

var newData = data.map((item) => {
  var animalTypes = item.animals.map(animal => {
    return animal.name;
  };
  return {
    food: item.food,
    animalTypes: animalTypes
  };
}, []);
```

This is just vanilla JS but this should work the same in Angular. If you are new to the `map` function here is a good write up explaining them https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/javascripts-map-reduce-and-filter

Answer (score 1):

You could make a filter, so this way you can reuse the code through the entire application. The filter implementation might be different, according to your needs. Here I show an option and below there is a snippet with an entire example:

**Filter**:

```
.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (data, key, keyInKey, replacement) {
        if (data && angular.isArray(data)) {

            var aux;
            angular.forEach(data, function(obj){
                aux = "";
                if(obj[key]){
                    angular.forEach(obj[key], function(objInObj){
                        if(objInObj[keyInKey]){
                            aux += objInObj[keyInKey] + ", ";
                        }
                    });
                    delete obj[key];
                    obj[replacement] = aux.substring(0, aux.length - 2);
                }
            });
        }
        return data;
    }
})
```

**Snippet**

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])

.controller('foo', function($scope) {
  $scope.testData = [{
    food: 'wet',
    animal: [{
      name: 'cat',
      value: '1'
    }, {
      name: 'dog',
      value: '2'
    }]
  }, {
    food: 'dry',
    animal: [{
      name: 'bird',
      value: '3'
    }, {
      name: 'fish',
      value: '4'
    }]
  }];
})

.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(data, key, keyInKey, replacement) {
    if (data && angular.isArray(data)) {

      var aux;
      angular.forEach(data, function(obj) {
        aux = "";
        if (obj[key]) {
          angular.forEach(obj[key], function(objInObj) {
            if (objInObj[keyInKey]) {
              aux += objInObj[keyInKey] + ", ";
            }
          });
          delete obj[key];
          obj[replacement] = aux.substring(0, aux.length - 2);
        }
      });
    }
    return data;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="foo">

    <div ng-repeat="it in testData | myFilter:'animal':'name':'animalType'">

      <label>Food:</label>&nbsp;<span ng-bind="it.food"></span>
      <br/>
      <label>Animal type:</label>&nbsp;<span ng-bind="it.animalType"></span>

      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns the structure you're after, where the animalType value is a string of animals, not an array.

```
var testData = [
    {
        food: 'wet',
        animal: [{name: 'cat', value: '1'},
                {name: 'dog', value: '2'}]
    },
    {
        food: 'dry',
        animal: [{name: 'bird', value: '3'},
                {name: 'fish', value: '4'}]
    }
];

var newData = [];

for (var i=0;i < testData.length; i++) {

  var animalType = '';

  for (var j=0; j < testData[i]['animal'].length; j++) {
    animalType += testData[i].animal[j].name += ' ';
  }

  newData.push({
    food: testData[i].food,
    animalType: animalType
  });


}

console.log(newData);
```